# Use Application Web Config instead of IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-8

I'm facing a trouble when I try to run my application on my company server, on my local machine and IIS I don't have any problem. Playing with both (company server and my computer) IIS configuration I founded that the problem is with Web.config files. My web application web.config file is the following:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FilesPath" value="/MobileApp/Excel/"/>
    <add key="dbConn" value="Server=192.168.10.1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=A;User Id=sa;Password=1223;" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And here is the difference. On my local IIS root path the web.config is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And server web.config file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" mode="InProc" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".pac" mimeType="application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".jnpl" mimeType="application/x-java-jnlp-file" />
        </staticContent>
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <remove path="*" />
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="100-999" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What I'm trying is to execute an ajax call and on local IIS works fine, when I run the same code on server IIS I get a **401 Unauthorized** error message.

What could be the cause of this error? And if is the web.config file on server is there a way to avoid reading that file? Because it's easy for me to delete all but there is a lot of applications running on that server and if I remove something I don't know how it's going to affect the functionality.

**PD. On local IIS I use version 7.5 and on server I use IIS 8.**

Comment: Try to change your local settings to match the remote server. If that helps reproduce the issue, you can debug easily to learn what's wrong.

Comment: try to disable all the authentication if not necessary and enable anonymous authentication at the server level. as I can see in your application config file you enabled the form authentication and in server config file there is windows authentication is enabled.

Comment: @LexLi I put my local web config exactly as the remote server and I get the same error, that's why I discovered that the problem is that, the root web.config file. But as I said I'm trying to avoid all changes to remote server config file because there are a lot of applications running on that server and I can't test :(

Comment: @JalpaPanchal The same comment as above, I cannot change the remote server config file, a lot of applications are running there and I can't cause a downtime :(

Comment: "I put my local web config exactly as the remote server" is only part of equation. You need to clone more settings as they go across multiple files, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/understanding-iis-configuration-delegation#configuration-hierarchy-and-effective-configuration